# Json.data not loading/displaying properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to load mine data.json file so I can display text when I click on the button. I am new to wonders of JQuery so it is hard for me to understand how to do this properly.

This is mine json file, portion of html where I have tried to load mine json.data. You can see that i have tried to load json.data into html but when I do that nothing is displaying, and I rely do not know how to wrap this, want to achieve [this, but whit loading data.json into html](http://www.mattconnolly.com/Examples/CircleJQuery/test-circle.html). 
So can some one help me work this out.

```
[
    {
        "all": {
            "id": "all",
            "data": {
                "datatext": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
            }
        },
        "cover": {
            "id": "cover",
            "data": {
                "datatext": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
            }
        },
        "diy": {
            "id": "diy",
            "data": {
                "datatext": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
            }
        },
        "marketing": {
            "id": "marketing",
            "data": {
                "datatext": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
            }
        },
        "other": {
            "id": "other",
            "data": {
                "datatext": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
            }
        },
        "special": {
            "id": "special",
            "data": {
                "datatext": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
            }
        },
        "vip": {
            "id": "vip",
            "data": {
                "datatext": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
            }
        },
        "design": {
            "id": "design",
            "data": {
                "datatext": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Portion of HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang=""> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">



        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme-min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href="css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script>
          $.getJSON("json.data", function( json ){
            $('div[class^="move"]').on('click', function(){
              var id = $(this).attr('id');
              alert(a[id].data.datatext)
              $('#main-view').text(a[id].data.datatext); // in #main-view display text
            })
          });
        </script>

        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
        <!-- Navigation -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img style="height: 30px; margin-top: -5px;" class="img-responsive" alt="" src="img/logo/Logo.png">

        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li id="ribbon"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Protfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Membership Plan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

    <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <!--SERVICES SECTION -->

      <section class='circle-animation'>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-pull-1">
                <div id="middlepapir" class="jumbotron">
                  <div class="row">

                    <img id="main-view" class="papir img-responsive" src="img/circle/11.png" alt="">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div id="all" class="move1 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-push-4"> 
                          <a href="#"><img class="position1 round" src="img/circle/off/home-all-icon-off.png"></a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div id="cover" class="move2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-push-1">
                          <a href="#"><img class="position2 round" src="img/circle/off/home-cover-icon-off.png"></a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div id="design" class="move3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-push-7">
                          <a href="#"><img class="position3 round" src="img/circle/off/home-design-icon-off.png"></a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div id="diy" class="move4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                          <a href="#"><img class="position4 round" src="img/circle/off/home-diy-icon-off.png"></a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div id="marketing" class="move5 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-push-8">
                          <a href="#"><img class="position5 round" src="img/circle/off/home-marketing-icon-off.png"></a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div id="other" class="move6 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-push-1">
                          <a href="#"><img class="position6 round" src="img/circle/off/home-other-icon-off.png"></a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div id="special" class="move7 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-push-4">
                          <a href="#"><img class="position7 round" src="img/circle/off/home-special-icon-off.png"></a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div id="vip" class="move8 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-push-7">
                          <a href="#"><img class="position8 round" src="img/circle/off/home-vip-icon-off.png"></a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>   
              </div>  
            </div>  
          </div>    
        </div>
      </section>
            <!--end circle-container-->
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle out of this ?

Comment: wrap your js code inside $(document).ready(function() {  }), and try

Comment: Can you please update your code in http://plnkr.co/, so that we can help you.

Comment: @stanze just give me a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript snippet is running before the rest of the HTML has finished rendering.

This portion of code needs to be wrapped in a [$( document ).ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) call.

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("json.data", function( json ){
          $('div[class^="move"]').on('click', function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(a[id].data.datatext)
            $('#main-view').text(a[id].data.datatext); // in #main-view display text
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Or, you can move it to the bottom of your `<body></body>` tag. This is not as good a solution. Still wrap it in the document.ready method.

EDIT:

Since you were getting a **404 Not Found** error from the `$.getJSON()` AJAX call, it means you'll need a server.

Basically, If your `json.data` file isn't actually being served from localhost, you won't be able to just make ajax calls by loading the static html file into your web browser. [Setting up a simple Node.js server](http://dannydelott.com/creating-and-running-a-simple-node-js-server/) is pretty quick and painless.

You'll simply want to set up a route to serve up the json.data file. Take the `server.js` code snippet from that link and modify the GET Requests section to look like this:

```
/* **************
 * GET Requests *
 * **************/

// index.html
app.get(‘/‘, function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(‘index.html‘);
});

// json.data
app.get(‘json.data‘, function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(‘json.data‘);
});
```

Also, you should consider renaming `json.data` to `data.json`.

Comment: I have wrap the code like you proposed, but still not loading it, is there a bather way to load it into mine html, it is hard for me to make a fiddle example out of this, but I will try.

Comment: Is the Chrome console showing any errors from the ajax call  `.getJSON()`? Are you getting a 404 Not Found or anything?

Comment: Have you checked that your JSON is valid with a linter after modifying it? http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Will do, I am having some network problems, I will update mine progress sonn.

Comment: Mine json is valid, I have check that and I now I have made a pure json file, check the server in mine Chromium and yes it is displaying 404 page not found error, how can I fix this, so I can load it locally. I have updated mine data.json to new data.json. @DannyDelott

Comment: See my edit about how to resolve the 404 Page Not Found error you're getting from the AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if the json file is avaliable on your server. Just go to http://yourservername/json.data

Also, your json.data file shouldn't have any javascript it should be plain json. It should contain "{ ... }" instead of "var a = { ... }"

After you change the contents of the json file your javascript function should look something like this:

```
$.getJSON("json.data", function(json) {
    $('div[class^="move"]').on('click', function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(json[id].data.datatext)
        $('#main-view').text(json[id].data.datatext); // in #main-view display text
    })
});
```

Comment: Whait I do not need to wrap it around $(document).ready (function (){}), after I remove var a in data.json, I will chek the server after I manage to solve this network issues.